# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS - Wake on LAN not working - PC Powering on but not booting into OS

Tags: boot, networking, power-management, wakeonlan

I have a raspberry pi that I'm using to power on my old HP PC (HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF)
I have enabled Wake on LAN the ethernet interface of my PC by following instructions in https://linuxtut.com/en/a01adbf17d846beb4605/

When sent a magic packet from raspberry pi, my computer power on (I hear the CPU Fan spinning and see that the power leds flashing) but it doesn't boot into the OS

When I hookup a monitor, I can see that it boots to a blank screen with a blinking "_" at the top left. I had to press and hold the power button to turn it off and when I press the power button again it boots normally. or I could press Ctrl+Alt+Del on the keyboard and it restarts into the OS

I have a SSD as my boot drive and a 2-HDD raid for my media storage

I tried to research online but could not see any relevant experiences, and I'm fairly new to linux and so have a hard time deciphering.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Ace.

Comment: A lot of the desktop-class HP systems will not boot into an OS unless connected to a keyboard and monitor. If you would like to run the machine as a server, you'll want to check in the BIOS/UEFI whether there is a "Headless Mode" and enable that. If there isn't (there *usually* isn't), then you may need to get a VGA "dummy plug" to fool the machine into thinking a monitor is receiving signal. These can be found online for about $6.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

akay0402

My PC(HP Compaq 8200) didn't boot OS(Ubuntu 20.04) but just only power on, when receiving magic packet as well as you.

But after upgrading BIOS (below link), the PC became able to boot OS.

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-compaq-8200-elite-small-form-factor-pc/5037931/swItemId/vc-229778-2